# How can I get a datatable row's content with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried many examples returned by searching on jQuery datatable and so far have not found anything that can give me the contents of a selected row. The closest example I have found is [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html) one which, however, gives the numbers of rows selected, but neither the content of a selected row, nor how to find out which row and so on.

I'm actually only interested in a single selected row.

The lines of interest are:

```
action: function () {
    var count = table.rows( { selected: true } ).count();
    events.prepend( '<div>'+count+' row(s) selected</div>' );
}
```

I would like to be able to get the contents of the row (s). I actually only want a single row selected, but this example covers multiple lines.

An extract of the HTML and the full JavaScript is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var events = $('#events');
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    select: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Get selected data',
      action: function() {
        var count = table.rows({
          selected: true
        }).count();

        events.prepend('<div>' + count + ' row(s) selected</div>');
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables.net/2.1.1/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div id="events">
  Row selected count - new information added at the top
</div>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This website si all about code, nobody can help you without it. Make [mre] using <> button in editor to create a example fiddle.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I found an answer, its probably not the best.
Change : 
action: function() {
        var count = table.rows({
          selected: true
        }).count();

To 

var count = table.rows( { selected: true } ).data(); "
        + "                                var ug = count[0]; "

 + "    events.prepend( '<div>Selected  Row Data : '+ ug+' </div>'  ); "