# How can I fetch row values on button click for Jquery Datatable

Tags: html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I've created a datatable using jquery as below -

```
function LoadtblItemWiseOrder() {

$("#tblItemWiseOrder").DataTable().destroy();
var req = {
    "processing": true,
    "language": {
        processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "paging": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 5,
    "searching": true,
    "filter": true,
    "language": {
        "paginate": {
            "next": '&#8594;',
            "previous": '&#8592;'
        }
    },
    "ajax": {
        "url": window.LoadItemWiseOrders,
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": {}
    },
    'order': [[0, "asc"]],
    columns: [
        { title: "SNo", "data": "SNo", "name": "SNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "Id", "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "WA No", "data": "SoNoView", "name": "SoNoView", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "Customer Id", "data": "CustomerId", "name": "CustomerId", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "Customer Name", "data": "CustomerName", "name": "CustomerName", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "PO No", "data": "PoNo", "name": "PONo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "PO Date", "data": "PoDate", "name": "PODate", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "PO Delivery Date", "data": "PoDeliveryDate", "name": "PODeliveryDate", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "Supply", "data": "SupplyTerms", "name": "SupplyTerms", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "Supply Terms", "data": "SupplyTermsText", "name": "SupplyTermsText", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "QuoteNos", "data": "QuoteNo", "name": "QuoteNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "QuoteItems", "data": "QuoteItemSlNo", "name": "QuoteItemSlNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "Quote No", "data": "QuoteNoView", "name": "QuoteNoView", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "Quote Item Sl No", "data": "QuoteItemSlNoText", "name": "QuoteItemSlNoText", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        { title: "PO Sl No", "data": "PoSLNo", "name": "PoSLNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "PO Qty", "data": "PoQty", "name": "PoQty", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
        { title: "Unit Price", "data": "UnitPrice", "name": "UnitPrice", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
        {
            title: "Action", "data": "", orderable: false, width: "auto",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var columnVal = "";
                columnVal = '<div><button type = "button" onclick=EditOrderItems("' + $(this) + '") class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Edit </button><button type = "button" onclick=DeleteUsingItemId("' + full.Id + '") class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Delete </button></div>';
                return columnVal;
            }
        }
    ],
    "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
    },
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
    },
    "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {

    }
}

$("#tblItemWiseOrder").DataTable(req);
$("#tblItemWiseOrder tbody").show();
```

}

The HTML has fixed header As -

```
<table id="tblItemWiseOrder" class="table table-striped table-info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>SNo</td>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>Order Type</td>
                            <td>WA No</td>
                            <td>Customer Id</td>
                            <td>Customer Name</td>
                            <td>PO No</td>
                            <td>PO Date</td>
                            <td>PO Delivery Date</td>
                            <td>Supply</td>
                            <td>Supply Terms</td>
                            <td>QuoteNos</td>
                            <td>Quote No</td>
                            <td>Quote Items</td>
                            <td>Quote Item Sl No</td>
                            <td>PO Sl No</td>
                            <td>PO Qty</td>
                            @*<td>Unit Price</td>*@
                            <td>Action</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
```

Now, I want that on button click `<button type = "button" onclick=EditOrderItems("' + $(this) + '") class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Edit </button>` my function is called with all row values. But I can't get all values of row -

```
function  EditOrderItems(thisObj) {

thisObj.parent().parent().children().each(function () {
    alert("childs");
});
}
```

But I can't get the values I've searched many places similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643901/how-can-i-get-a-datatable-rows-content-with-jquery). Also I want to pass row data as a parameter to function. So, is this possible?

**EDIT:**
I've modified the table structure as suggested in answer as -

```
    var myData = [];
function LoadtblItemWiseOrder() {

    $("#tblItemWiseOrder").DataTable().destroy();
    var req = {
        "processing": true,
        "language": {
            processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
        },
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 5,
        "searching": true,
        "filter": true,
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "next": '&#8594;',
                "previous": '&#8592;'
            }
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url": window.LoadItemWiseOrders,
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            "data": {},
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                myData = json.data;
                return json.data;
            }
        },
        'order': [[0, "asc"]],
        columns: [
            { title: "SNo", "data": "SNo", "name": "SNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "Id", "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "WA No", "data": "SoNoView", "name": "SoNoView", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "Customer Id", "data": "CustomerId", "name": "CustomerId", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "Customer Name", "data": "CustomerName", "name": "CustomerName", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "PO No", "data": "PoNo", "name": "PONo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "PO Date", "data": "PoDate", "name": "PODate", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "PO Delivery Date", "data": "PoDeliveryDate", "name": "PODeliveryDate", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "Supply", "data": "SupplyTerms", "name": "SupplyTerms", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "Supply Terms", "data": "SupplyTermsText", "name": "SupplyTermsText", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "QuoteNos", "data": "QuoteNo", "name": "QuoteNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "QuoteItems", "data": "QuoteItemSlNo", "name": "QuoteItemSlNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "Quote No", "data": "QuoteNoView", "name": "QuoteNoView", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "Quote Item Sl No", "data": "QuoteItemSlNoText", "name": "QuoteItemSlNoText", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },
            { title: "PO Sl No", "data": "PoSLNo", "name": "PoSLNo", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "PO Qty", "data": "PoQty", "name": "PoQty", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false },
            { title: "Unit Price", "data": "UnitPrice", "name": "UnitPrice", "autoWidth": true, "visible": true },            
            {
                data: 'id',
                title: "Action", "data": "", orderable: false, width: "auto",
                render: value => `<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm editItemBtn" data-id="${value}">Edit</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteItemBtn" data-id="${value}">Delete</button></div>`
            }
        ],
        "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        },
        "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        },
        "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {

        }
    }

    $("#tblItemWiseOrder").DataTable(req);
    $("#tblItemWiseOrder tbody").show();
}
```

And function call as -

```
var table = $('#tblItemWiseOrder');

table.on('click', '.editItemBtn', function () {
    const id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    const data = myData.find(d => d.id == Id);
    const data1 = myData.find(d => d.id == SoNoView);
    console.log(data+' '+data1);

})

table.on('click', '.deleteItemBtn', function () {
    const id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    const data = myData.find(d => d.id == id);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using an object for `ajax` you could make use of the [dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) property. This can be used to define which property of your response object to use as your data, but it can also accept a function. In the function save the response data as a local JavaScript array and return your data.

```js
const myData = [];
```

```js
ajax: {
    url: window.LoadItemWiseOrders,
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {}
    dataSrc: function(json) {
        myData = json.data;
        return json.data;
    }
}
```

Then when you define your button give it a class and a `data-id` attribute (I prefer to put all javascript in its own file rather than use `onclick()`). You can also simplify your `render` statement by specifying which `data` property you want it to use, and by taking advantage of the arrow function's default return feature. Use backticks for the string so that you don't need to concatenate.

```js
{
    data: 'id',
    title: "Action", orderable: false, width: "auto",
    render: value => `<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm edit" data-id="${value}">Edit</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" data-id="${value}">Delete</button></div>`
}
```

Finally, create an event handler in your JavaScript file to handle the button click from the class, and search your `myData` array for this row's data.

```js
const table = $("#tblItemWiseOrder").DataTable(req);

table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
    const id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    const data = myData.find( d => d.id == id );
}

table.on('click', '.delete', function() {
    const id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    const data = myData.find( d => d.id == id );
}
```

Once you have made your changes and successfully saved them to the database you can reload your table, which will repopulate your `myData` array.

```js
table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have applied this but when I click my edit button `table.on('click', '.edit', function() {` is not getting called.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your button has the `edit` class? I've edited my post to clarify that the JavaScript table variable needs to be the Datatable. Also, unless you are changing the structure of your table it is easier to let ajax refresh your data using the `reload()` function instead of destroying it and recreating it every time. If you need to change the URL, that is also possible.

Comment: Yes, I've modified it and included the classes. I'll modify my question to let you see the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Modified in Edit Part. Please see.